# Computer Vision for Windows on ARM (WinRT)

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, windows-store-apps

I am learning [FastCV (Alpha) for Windows RT](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv/tools-and-resources). According to [Getting Started guide](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv/getting-started-guide):

> The first implementation is designed to run efficiently on any ARM processor, and is named ‘FastCV for ARM.’ The second FastCV implementation runs only on Qualcomm SoC’s and is called ‘FastCV for Snapdragon.’ ‘FastCV for Snapdragon’ has the same API as ‘FastCV for ARM,’ but it provides hardware accelerated implementations of the CV functions included in the library.

Then the metro lib integration guide say:

> ***Configuration Manager*** as highlighted should be set to Release Mode (metro lib is compiled for this mode) and the platform should be set to ARM. If ARM does not appear by default, click add new platform -> ARM in configuration manager.

**Questions:**

- Does it mean we cannot consume this library on Windows Store apps running on ia/x86 systems?
- Would FastCV code run only on Snapdragon or other ARM processors too (like Tegra 3)?
- Is there any other implementation of CV for OCR on Windows RT?

Comment: You might have better luck asking on the fastcv forum. https://developer.qualcomm.com/forums/qdevnet-forums/computer-vision-fastcv

Comment: @Roddy, Thanks. I have [posted](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdevnet-forums/computer-vision-fastcv/22738) on Qualcomm forums. Is there any C++ only library for OCR? I am trying to convert [tesseract](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn-history/r683/trunk/vs2008/doc/setup.html) project, but it has dependencies like zlib which are build in C (for x86/x64). Is there a way to port C libs in WinRT runtime (like there are ways to import C++ libraries)?